# is there any difference between the shutdown option and cli shutdown

Tags: shutdown

Do they do different things? 
is there any actual difference as in if I force shutdown will it damage anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shutdown through gui and cli are similar since they run pre shutdown scripts to safely close any running programs and power off. Gui shutdown runs through dbus service , and cli through linux default tools.

Pressing power off button and holding will cause the machine to power off immediately without closing programs, so data may be lost.

Comment: Power Off Button and the file and disk metadata, kept in RAM for quick, easy access, will not be written to disk, leading to disk corruption.